# Connect Estimote Beacons to Database/cloud and featch the information From Database/cloud in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, ibeacon, xcode5.0.1

I just got my pack of Estimote iBeacons and I have Fetch the Basic information like Major and Minor Values.

I know that the **UUID** for an Estimote beacon is always **B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D**. But how would i connect device to database/cloud and how can fetch the data from my local database/cloud.

Any assistance would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: +10 even i was looking for this

Answer (score 0):

How about this sample code.
https://github.com/AlohaYos/LocatedItems

This sample use major/minor number to select web urls.
You can modify this sample in order to access your own database.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build your own database and transport layer, Radius Networks (my company) offers a web service called [ProximityKit](http://www.proximitykit.com) that lets you set up your iBeacon uuid/major/minor values in the cloud and attach key/value pairs to them.

You first need to find out your iBeacon's identifiers.  The easiest way to do this is to use one of our scanner tools like [Locate for iBeacon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-for-ibeacon/id738709014?mt=8) (free) or [ScanBeacon](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/scanbeacon-app.html) for Mac.

Once you have these identifiers, you can configure that iBeacon to ProximityKit, and you can then read the key/value pairs each time the iBeacon is detected.  This way, you can change the data on the fly without baking it into your app and waiting for AppStore approval each time you need to make a change.

Below is an example of what a setup might look like:

[image]